# Issues using OAuth2 to authorize in gspread using python

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gspread

I am very new with python so please excuse my ignorance.

I am trying to send data to Google spreadsheets and have decided to use [gspread.](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)

However gspread requires me to use OAuth-2.0 to authorize access to the spreadsheets. I have used the [tutorial](http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html) on their documentation page to do so. However when I execute my code:

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

json_key = json.load(open('test IGS-1859066a1c38.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['760 ... 6r9@developer.gserviceaccount.com'], json_key['-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMI ... 003d\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'], scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("ITGS_TEST").sheet1
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: '760 ... 6r9@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
```

I don't know how to fix this, and don't see what I am missing. I would appreciate it if anyone could provide their input.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I followed Sandeep107 advice and changed my code back to:

```
SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
```

I no longer get the old error code, instead however I get the following error:

```
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'],  json_key['private_key'], scope)
  File "F:\Python33\lib\site-packages\oauth2client-1.4.7-py3.3.egg\oauth2client\util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Python33\lib\site-packages\oauth2client-1.4.7-py3.3.egg\oauth2client\client.py", line 1487, in __init__
    self.private_key = base64.b64encode(private_key)
  File "F:\Python33\lib\base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    raise TypeError("expected bytes, not %s" % s.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: expected bytes, not str
```

Again any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key']** as is.

No need to replace with actual values.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help! I tried to follow you suggestion, unfortunately it  gives me another error. See edit for details.

Comment: @user3120921 have u resolved this issue? If not, please give more specifics.. have you changed the .json file?

Answer (score 0):

Check link: http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html

I think you need the "client_email."  Looks like you may have "client_key" twice.

Let me know how you make out.  I am trying to work through this whole oauth2 thing myself and it is not going very well.

Comment: Link only answers without any further information are problematic. If the link's target changes, your answer becomes useless. Improve your answer by using the edit button and include the relevant information in it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I checked and I am defiantly using the client email

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 requires a string to be cast as bytes, Python 2.x uses a string, which Python version are you using?